# How do I programatically get my Azure storage endpoint URLs?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm fairly new to Azure and I'm using Blob storage to store some binary images, but I can't seem to figure out how to programatically get my Azure storage endpoint URLs?

I am trying to render out some `<img>` tags that render correctly locally using the simulator, or when deployed to my live Azure instance.

So for example if I launch my site locally it would render out as:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/uploads/image.jpg" />
```

and when deployed to Azure it would render out as:

```
<img src="http://example.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/image.jpg" />
```

Obviously one way would be to just store it as a setting in my **ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg** and **ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg** files, but there must be a way to get this value programatically.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that your connection strings should be stored in your configuration, and you can have different values for local and cloud. This is very simple to get at, programmatically:

First, make sure you set a config setting publisher during role startup:

```
CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) => configSetter(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName)));
```

Now just retrieve your storage account and pull the URL:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("MyStorage");
var urlBase = storageAccount.BlobEndpoint;
```

At this point, you'd base your `IMG` tags off `urlBase`.